# Неориентированный граф: оптимальное создание

Tags: графы, java, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Всем добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом оптимальнее создавать неориентированный граф, столько разных структур существует в `Java`:

1. Можно в виде матрицы смежности, создав просто 2-мерный массив (что не очень оптимально, так что сразу был отброшен)
2. Можно переделать тип `Iterator<Integer>` в `Bag<Integer>`, сделав список смежных вершин (тогда это будет выглядеть примерно так: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Bag.java.html, неплохой вариант, в принципе)
3. Можно сделать все это с помощью `Map` и `TreeMap` (видел один пример, понравился по компактности, но не знаю, будет ли это приемлемо, или же нет)
4. Также вот увидел вариант с помощью [`Hashmap`](http://jdevnotes.blogspot.ru/2011/01/blog-post_11.html)

Вот в общем, такие у меня варианты есть. Я не силен в `Java`, еще только начинаю в нем разбираться. Подскажите, каким образом решить данный вопрос. Спасибо большое заранее!

Comment: А ссылка на Hashmap похоже битая....

    К сожалению, страница, которую вы искали в этом блоге, не существует. 

На самом деле Map это хороший вариант, а TreeMap или HashMap это просто  разные реализации того же алгоритма. 

Интуитивно, хэшмап должен быть быстрее, но возможно потребует переопределения метода hashCode() для ключа. Поэтому, с учетом "Я не силен в Java...", лучше попробовать TreeMap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конкретный язык прграммирования тут ни при чем! Видимо, если Вы не сильны в Java, то **пока** не сильны и вообще в *алгоритмах и структурах данных*. Поэтому рекомендую не думать на данном этапе о сверхэффективности Вашего кода.

Используйте **классические** структуры данных для представления графа: **матрицу смежности** или **списки смежности** (это 1й и 2й пункты из Вашего вопроса). Возьмите [хорошую книгу](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2429691/) и реализуйте граф так, как там описано внутри класса `граф` (в зоне `private`).

Добавьте `public`-интерфейс, который нужен для конкретной задачи.
Реализуйте по книге алгоритмы обхода графа. Запрогрпмируйте какую-нибудь олимпиадную задачу с помощью Вашего класса. Если Вы сделаете *обе* реализации, сможете сравнить производительность.

Успехов!